# Are APIs basically disabled by default? (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, default, disable

I've used **many APIs** on **GCP** then I found **most of APIs are disabled by default** for example:

**Cloud Run API**:

[image]

**Google Container Registry API**:

[image]

**Cloud Build API**:

[image]

**Compute Engine API**:

[image]

And **some of APIs are enabled by default** for example:

**Cloud Storage**:

[image]

**Cloud SQL**:

[image]

So, on **GCP**, are **APIs basically disabled by default**?

Comment: Agree its counterintuitive why some APIs are enabled why others are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, on **GCP**, **APIs are basically disabled by default**. There are [**more than 250 APIs on GCP**](https://gist.github.com/coryodaniel/13eaee16a87a7fdca5e738123216862a)

And, [**only these 14 APIs**](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enabled-service#default) below are enabled by default:

- BigQuery API
- BigQuery Storage API
- Cloud Datastore API
- Cloud Debugger API
- Cloud Logging API
- Cloud Monitoring API
- Cloud SQL
- Cloud Storage
- Cloud Storage API
- Cloud Trace API
- Google Cloud APIs
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API
- Service Management API
- Service Usage API